Parsing Significand Bits Procedure MIPS
I am currently working on a MIPS program which takes in user input as a decimal then gives the sign, exponent, significand bits, truncated unsigned int, and truncated int. I'm having trouble with my parse_significand procedure and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.
 # Procedure to parse and interpret the significand (mantissa) and add the implied 1
parse_significand:
    andi $v0, $a0, 0x7FFFFF     
    ori  $v0, $v0, 0x800000      
    jr   $ra


What kind of trouble are you having, specifically? Please ask a specific technical question. What output do you expect and what are you getting for a particular input?

I am using a test case of 3.75 where I know the output should be: 00000000100101010000001011111001 But I am outputting: 00000000000000000000000000000100

Please [edit] the question to show a [mcve] with input and output, then ask a technical question about your code--where did your debugging efforts lead and what specific step of the debugging process isn't making sense?

Your mask, 0x7FFFFF, is correct as is your hidden one bit, 0x800000.  However, 3.75₁₀ in IEEE754 is 01000000011100000000000000000000₂.  After masking that becomes 00000000011100000000000000000000 and after introducing the hidden 1 bit, 00000000111100000000000000000000.  So, your test case, not shown, is doing something incorrect.

@ErikEidt In the entire program I am also parsing the sign, and exponent prior to the significand bits. Maybe those procedures/register use are not working properly?

"3.75 where I know the output should be: 00000000100101010000001011111001" — curious, how do you arrive at this?

@ErikEidt apologies, you are correct that the output should be: 00000000111100000000000000000000, I entered the wrong numbers. Mistakes arising from staring at my screen for hours
